# PHP: using function in other files before include

Tags: php

should this work? and why not?

file: run.php

```
<?php 
   test(); 
   include('function.php');
?>
```

file: function.php

```
<?php
   function test(){echo 'working';}
?>
```

since this would work just fine

```
<?php
   test();
   function test(){echo 'working';}
?>
```

Comment: No,the first example with two files won't work because the include will only be executed when PHP reaches that particular line of code, and so you're trying to call test() before PHP has seen its definition

Comment: Whereas in the second case, PHP has parsed the entire file, so it knows about the test() function before it starts to execute that file

Comment: i know that, but i always thought that the include and require will be done before executing the code.. seems wrong!

Comment: No, they're executed only when that line is reached in the code, which is why you can use includes that return a value that is then assigned to a variable, or use includes inside an if/else

Comment: why i'm getting -3? anyone can explain?

Comment: Neither of those examples will display `-3`, so it's impossible to explain

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

You can call a function which is defined after calling it. That's because PHP first parses the file and then executes it. That's why your third snippet works.